# Conan Cross-build from Linux:x86_64 to Linux:armv7hf test_package build fails

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, conan, cross-build

I have a C++ library packaged with conan and it contains a `test_package` with a `conanfile.py` that uses the new conan 2.0 `self.requries(self.tested_reference_str)` and `test_type = "explicit"`.

When **not** cross-building everything runs fine. I can build the library using `conan build .` and build and run the consumer `test_package`.

In case of cross-building, the main library can be built without issues. However, the build of the `test_package` fails with:

```
----Running------
> . "/work/tests/test_package/build/generators/conanbuild.sh" && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/work/tests/test_package/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "/work/tests/test_package/."
-----------------
-- Using Conan toolchain: /work/tests/test_package/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ - broken
CMake Error at /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /work/tests/test_package/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_8ea64/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/work/tests/test_package/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types    -stdlib=libstdc++  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /work/tests/test_package/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-stdlib=libstdc++’
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ea64.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/work/tests/test_package/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_8ea64/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

host profile:

```
[settings]
os=Linux
arch=armv7hf
compiler=clang
compiler.version=14
# Tried also with libc++
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
```

build profile:

```
[settings]
os=Linux
arch=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=11
# Without the following the error becomes:
# arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release

[env]
CC=gcc-11
CXX=g++-11
```

Any idea why cross compiling works for the library itself but the test_package fails?

---

Edit: I looked into `conaninfo.txt`, `CMakeCache.txt`, for both: the library generated files and the `test_package` generated files. Conan specifies the clang compiler in both cases (library build and `test_package`) but CMake uses anyway the GNU compiler for the `test_package`. It seems the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is not passed correctly to CMake in case of the `test_package`. A `conan install` inside the `test_packag`e folder also results in the wrong compiler (GNU) being used.

Comment: The recipes and full instructions to reproduce are very important to try to understand what could be happening. I'd recommend to submit an issue with those details to https://github.com/conan-io/conan for checking.

Comment: I've stumbled upon the exact same problem now - Have you managed to overcome it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was because [apply_env](https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#apply-env) was set to false in the test_package conan recipe. Removing the line helped.